# How to update a CSV file using its package

Tags: python, csv

Here's my code:

```
def update_win():
    #GET EVERY STRING VALUES NEEDED FROM INPUTBAR
    stud_ID = str(ID_num.get())
    stud_name = str(name.get())
    stud_course = str(Crs.get())
    stud_year = str(Yr.get())
    searchID = str(sID_num.get())#ID NUMBER FOR SEARCH
    filename = str(files.get())#FILENAME                
    tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False)
    fields = ['ID', 'Name', 'Course', 'Year']

    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile, tempfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(tempfile, fieldnames=fields)
        for row in reader:
            if row['ID'] == searchID:
                row['Name'], row['Course'], row['Year'] = stud_name, stud_course, stud_year
                msg = Label(upd_win, text="Update Successful", font="fixedsys 12 bold").place(x=3,y=200)
            row = {'ID': row['ID'], 'Name': row['Name'], 'Course': row['Course'], 'Year': row['Year']}
            writer.writerow(row)

    shutil.move(tempfile.name, filename)
```

So this code is an UPDATE, it searches that ID number from the CSV, and shows its rows via a GUI as you can see its not `print` but `Label`, after that it prompts the user to enter the new ID number, new name, new course, and new year, you want to replace to the row you have selected.

It does get through, but the value doesn't change. Any ideas what happened here  and how I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting (printing) `row` in process to see what is happening? Or re-winding `tempfile` and inspecting it before the context manager exits? - you might want to write a separate script with some fake data to test just this functionality instead of trying to debug it in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you need to isolate your problem by writing separate scripts to test your processes.  This exercise is the first step to creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for posting here.  Oftentimes, creating an mcve helps you find the problem even before you post the question.

Here is a script to test whether the read-modify-write process works:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import io

s = '''one, two, three
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
'''

data_csv = io.StringIO(s)
g = NamedTemporaryFile(mode = 'w', delete = False)
fields = ['a', 'b', 'c']

# read-modify-write
with data_csv as f, g:
    w = csv.DictWriter(g, fields)
    w.writeheader()
    r = csv.DictReader(f, fields)
    for line in r:
        line['b'] = 'bar'
        w.writerow(line)

# test - did the modifications get written to a temp file?
with open(g.name) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Which does seem to be working, the tempfile has modified data in it.

---

Maybe *HOW* you modified the data is the problem - but changing the test script to match the *form* of your code also works fine

```
...
    for line in r:
        line['a'], line['b'], line['c'] = line['a'], 'foo', line['c']
        line = {'a':line['a'], 'b':line['b'], 'c':line['c']}
        w.writerow(line)
```

---

**Assuming** all the `.get()`'s in the first lines of the function are working, `filename` in the line

```
shutil.move(tempfile.name, filename)
```

must not have the correct path.

**OR** the conditional

```
if row['ID'] == searchID:
```

isn't working.

---

Food for thought:

Moving code into functions, like the read-modify-write portion, can not only help with readability, it can make testing easier.

`update_win()` works by using a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) (`shutil.move(tempfile.name, filename)`) instead of returning something that can be acted on. Side effects can make testing harder.

That isn't necessarily bad (sometimes it is practical), you just need to be aware that you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have opened both files for 'r' read and you are trying to write to temp file.

You can use 'r+' mode with one file handle in order to read and write to a file

```
...
with open(filename, 'r+') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
    ...
```